# undefined variable error

Tags: php, html

i am getting an error `Undefined variable: last_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\how are things\admin panel\editaggrement.phpon line 130` when i change my table row below,is there a way i can make this error the variable is defined but when i change my table row to div im getting the error

```
<tr>
     <td width="179"><b><font color='#663300'>Last Name<em>*</em></font></b></td>
     <td><label>
      <input type="text" name="last_name" value="<?php echo $last_name; ?>" />
     </label></td>
   </tr>
```

to a div like this below on my form

```
   <div class="field">
    <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
   <input type="text" class="input" id="last_name" name="last_name" value="<?php echo $last_name; ?>" maxlength="30"/>
<p class="hint">30 characters maximum (letters only)</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm guessing one of those is before the code that sets `$last_name`? Move the setting code above both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do something like

```
<?php echo isset($last_name) ? $last_name : '' ?>
```

If the variable's not defined, you'll just output an empty string (`''`) instead.